# using recursion and default value to draw a pattern based on input

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I have this code:

```
def pattern1(n, b=n):
  if n == 1:
    return 'A|'*b
  else:
    return 'A|'*b + '\n' + pattern1(n-1, b)

print(pattern1(5))
```

so when i called the pattern1 method with 1 argument, the default second argument should have the same value, so this is not working, is there any code equivalent?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there desired output?

Answer (score 0):

You can't refer to other parameters in the function definition, but you can easily do this in the code as follows:

```
def pattern1(n, b):
  if not b:
    b = n
  if n == 1:
    return 'A|'*b
  else:
    return 'A|'*b + '\n' + pattern1(n-1, b)

print(pattern1(5))
```

However it looks like in your code `b` is always `n` before you subtract 1, so just copy `n` before you modify it and don't pass a second parameter around:

```
def pattern1(n):
  if n == 1:
    return 'A|'*n
  else:
    n_copy = n
    return 'A|'*n + '\n' + pattern1(n-1, n_copy)

print(pattern1(5))
```